# Repeat single line in Imacros Script

Tags: imacros

I want to repeat this line in my iMacros code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Unfollow
```

Is there any way I can do it without copying and pasting the same line again below multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change position of unfollow

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Unfollow
```

If you want to repeat the line without any change

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Unfollow
```

And in iMacros panel enter how many loops you want. Then press `Play(Loop)`.

It's good to write macro like this

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Unfollow
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Works better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var macro;
    var repeat = 5;
    macro = "CODE:";
    for (i=0; i < repeat; i++) {
       macro += 'TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Unfollow' + "\n ";
    }
    iret = iimPlay(macro);
```

**Save this in *loop.js***